# Creating a border with System.out.println()

Tags: java

Is there anyway to create this sort of arrangement, without the `String` variable `sh3` affecting the border? I'm really stumped here, my Java knowledge is pretty much limited to what you see here if that helps?

```
System.out.println("###################################################"); 
System.out.println("#    **** WEST END THEATRE BOOKING SYSTEM ****    #"); 
System.out.println("#                                                 #"); 
System.out.println("#                 T I C K E T                     #"); 
System.out.println("#                                                 #"); 
System.out.println("#     Show:    "+sh3+"                            #"); 
System.out.println("#     Theatre: Her Majesty's                      #"); 
System.out.println("#     Price:   65                                 #"); 
System.out.println("###################################################");
```

Comment: That's a nice ticket!

Comment: very nice arrangement by the way:-D

Comment: print spaces in loop based on total length - length of string variable

Comment: You need to fix the number of characters for sh3 and stick with the border

Comment: Also take care that the show name should not exceed the total length of the ticket width.

Comment: Please, check my solution for this trouble in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790698/console-output-to-frame-text-area/75278927#75278927 Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I am not providing the code for this, but I am pointing to the process of thinking and then leaving implementation to you.

There are 4 properties in play, out of which you know the `total size of line`, also you know the `length of the string` and you know how much space is to be left  can be easily found.

And all you will need is a loop that will calculate how much spaces should be left.

[image]

Comment: +1 for identifying the basic concepts instead of just dumping code.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush Thanks. Yes its better to show path than just give the whole code and not let OP think anything. IMHO

Answer (score 6):

Since you know the length of the line, and all lines have the same length, you can do something like that:

Suppose `n` is the length of the line. Since `sh3` will begin from the 15 place, you can calculate how many spaces are needed after `sh3`.

```
System.out.println("#     Show:    "+sh3+calcSpaces()+"#");
```

Where `calcSpaces` can easily be implemented as you know the length of `sh3`..

```
private String calcSpaces(String sh3) {
    String res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < n - sh3.length(); i++){
       res += " ";  //You might want to use StringBuilder instead.. 
    }               //it's a good practice, although performance is not 
}                   //significant here
```

I also advise you to read about [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: I didn't test the `calcSpaces` method, but the concept is clear.

Comment: care needs to be taken if `sh3.length()` exceeds `n`

Comment: @NarendraPathai Good note. Indeed, OP has some additional things to do.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would use either a [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) or `PrintStream`'s [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

You can use `printf()` like this:

```
System.out.printf("#     Show:    %-35#\n", sh3);
```

When the first string gets printed, the `%-35` in it gets replaced with `sh3` plus some spaces. The `%` begins the escape sequence, the `-` makes `sh3` be on the left side of the allocated space, and the `35` allocates 35 characters of space for `sh3`. Any of those 35 characters not filled by `sh3` get filled with spaces.

To read more about `printf()`'s syntax, go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

EDIT: I forgot to mention the `\n`. In a `String`, `\n` is an escape sequence which creates a new line. e.g.:

```
System.out.println("abc\n123");
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println("abc");
System.out.println("123");
```

`printf()`, unlike `println()`, does not create a new line at the end of the `String` it prints. The `\n` manually creates a new line, which is necessary to make the program act as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is tricky way:

```
        String sh3 = "StackOverflow";
        String sh4 = "";
        for(int i=0;i<35-sh3.length();i++){
            sh4 += " ";
        }
        sh4 += "#";
        System.out.println("###################################################"); 
        System.out.println("#    **** WEST END THEATRE BOOKING SYSTEM ****    #"); 
        System.out.println("#                                                 #"); 
        System.out.println("#                 T I C K E T                     #"); 
        System.out.println("#                                                 #"); 
        System.out.println("#     Show:    " + sh3 + sh4 ); 
        System.out.println("#     Theatre: Her Majesty's                      #"); 
        System.out.println("#     Price:   65                                 #"); 
        System.out.println("###################################################");
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way would be:

```
System.out.print("#     Show:    " + sh3);
for (int i = 0; i < 34-sh3.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println(" #");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the length of sh3 using `sh3.length()`
Then you can add spaces to fit your border.

```
int spacesNum = 35 - sh3.length();
String spaces = "";
for(int i = spacesNum; i > 0; i++){
    spaces += " ";
}

System.out.println("###################################################"); 
System.out.println("#    **** WEST END THEATRE BOOKING SYSTEM ****    #"); 
System.out.println("#                                                 #"); 
System.out.println("#                 T I C K E T                     #"); 
System.out.println("#                                                 #"); 
System.out.println("#     Show:    "+sh3+spaces+"#"); 
System.out.println("#     Theatre: Her Majesty's                      #"); 
System.out.println("#     Price:   65                                 #"); 
System.out.println("###################################################");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Two seconds contribuition.. Alittle overkill, but it fits the demand...

Check in: https://github.com/codegtd/tdd-log-panel

```java
public class ConsolePanel {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    panel(
         21,
         2,
         3,
         3,
         Border.BOLD,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.THIN,
         true,
         true,
         "My Title", "My First Topic text", "My Second Topic text"
    );
  }

  public static void simplePanel(String... texts) {

    panel(
         21,
         5,
         1,
         1,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.THIN,
         Border.THIN,
         true,
         true,
         texts
    );
  }

  public static void simplePanelScalable(int scale, String... texts) {

    panel(
         scale,
         5,
         1,
         1,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.THIN,
         Border.THIN,
         true,
         true,
         texts
    );
  }

  public static void panel(
       int scale,
       int margin,
       int upSpace,
       int downSpace,
       Border cornersFormat,
       Border centerMarksFormat,
       Border horizontalLinesFormat,
       Border verticalLinesFormat,
       boolean uppercaseTitle,
       boolean centralizeTitle,
       String... titleAndOthers) {

    var estimatedAdjustmentFactor = 3;
    var title = titleAndOthers[0];
    var marginTitle = scale - (title.length() / 2) - estimatedAdjustmentFactor;
    var formattedTexts =
         Stream.of(titleAndOthers)
               .map(item -> item.equals(title) && centralizeTitle ? " ".repeat(
                    marginTitle) + title : item)
               .map(item -> item.equals(
                    title) && uppercaseTitle ? item.toUpperCase() : item)
               .toArray();

    var marginLimitedBySize = Math.min(margin, scale);

    // scale + margin discrepacies eliminated
    if (marginLimitedBySize % 2 != 0) -- marginLimitedBySize;
    if (scale % 2 != 0) ++ scale;

    int fullSize = (scale * 2) - marginLimitedBySize;
    if (fullSize % 2 == 0) ++ fullSize;
    else -- fullSize;

    var whitespaceMargin = " ".repeat(marginLimitedBySize);
    var externalUpSpaces = "\n".repeat(upSpace);
    var externalBottomSpaces = "\n".repeat(downSpace);

    var upperFace = upperLine(scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalLinesFormat);
    var divider = middleLine(scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalLinesFormat);
    var bottomFace = bottomLine(scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalLinesFormat);
    var faceLine = faceLine(verticalLinesFormat);

    var titleTextArea = String.valueOf(fullSize);
    var textPreparation = new StringBuilder();
    textPreparation.append(externalUpSpaces)
                   .append(upperFace)
                   .append(faceLine)
                   .append("%s%%-%ss".formatted(whitespaceMargin, titleTextArea))
                   .append(faceLine)
                   .append("\n")
                   .append(divider);

    // "-1" Because the first element in the Array was used as title
    // The discont-number in bodyTextArea/fullsize, subtract the size of "ordinal-ASC" and ") "
    var bodyTextArea = String.valueOf(fullSize - 4);
    var topicEnumeration = 0;
    var ordinalSymbolEnumerator = '\u2070';
    for (int i = formattedTexts.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      ++ topicEnumeration;
      textPreparation.append(faceLine)
                     .append("%s%s%s) %%-%ss".formatted(
                          whitespaceMargin,
                          topicEnumeration,
                          ordinalSymbolEnumerator,
                          bodyTextArea
                     ))
                     .append(faceLine)
                     .append("\n");
    }
    textPreparation.append(bottomFace)
                   .append(externalBottomSpaces);
    System.out.printf(textPreparation.toString(), formattedTexts);
  }

  private static String generateLine(char baseChar, int scale, char BASE_LINE) {

    return
         String
              .valueOf(baseChar)
              .repeat(scale)
              .replace(baseChar, BASE_LINE);
  }

  private static String upperLine(
       int scale,
       Border corner,
       Border centerMark,
       Border line) {

    ArrayList<Character> borderStylingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case THIN -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case DOUBLE -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    switch (line) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    var baseline = generateLine('_', scale, borderStylingItems.get(3));

    return borderStylingItems.get(0) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(2) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(1) + "\n";
  }

  private static String middleLine(
       int scale,
       Border corner,
       Border centerMark,
       Border baseLine
  ) {

    ArrayList<Character> borderStylingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code);
      }
      case THIN -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code);
      }
      case DOUBLE -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code);
      }
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    switch (baseLine) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    var divider = generateLine('_', scale, borderStylingItems.get(3));

    return borderStylingItems.get(0) + divider +
           borderStylingItems.get(2) + divider +
           borderStylingItems.get(1) + "\n";
  }

  private static String bottomLine(
       int scale,
       Border corner,
       Border centerMark,
       Border baseLine) {

    ArrayList<Character> borderStylingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case THIN -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case DOUBLE -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    switch (baseLine) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    var baseline = generateLine('_', scale, borderStylingItems.get(3));

    return borderStylingItems.get(0) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(2) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(1) + "\n";
  }

  private static Character faceLine(Border corner) {

    return switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> BoldFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      case THIN -> ThinFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      case DOUBLE -> DoubleFont.FACE_LINE.code;
    };
  }

  private enum BoldFont {

    FACE_LINE('\u2503'),
    BASE_LINE('\u2501'),
    UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250F'),
    UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2513'),
    MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2523'),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u252B'),
    LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2517'),
    LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u251B');

    private final char code;

    BoldFont(char code) {

      this.code = code;
    }
  }

  private enum ThinFont {

    FACE_LINE('\u2502'),
    BASE_LINE('\u2500'),
    UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250C'),
    UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2510'),
    MIDDLE_LEFT('\u252C'),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u2524'),
    LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2514'),
    LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2518');

    private final char code;

    ThinFont(char code) {

      this.code = code;
    }
  }

  private enum DoubleFont {

    FACE_LINE('\u2551'),
    BASE_LINE('\u2550'),
    UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2554'),
    UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2557'),
    MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2560'),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u2563'),
    LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u255A'),
    LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u255D');

    private final char code;

    DoubleFont(char code) {

      this.code = code;
    }
  }

  private enum Border {
    BOLD, THIN, DOUBLE
  }
}
```

[image]