# Console output to Frame, text area?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextarea

I am learning java, I have created a dice thrower - when i press the button it throws a dice - but the output is in the console. How can I output in the same frame with the buttons.

// sorry i am not native english speaking person, but i hope you get the idea.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main {

public static void main(String s[]){
    Random  rand = new Random();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Thrower 2000");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Throw dice");
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("You got : ");
    JTextArea output = new JTextArea(" a ");

    JButton buttond4  = new JButton();
    buttond4.setText("d4");
    buttond4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
            System.out.println("You threw d4 and got " + n);

        }
    });


    JButton buttond6 = new JButton();
    buttond6.setText("d6");
    buttond6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});

    JButton buttond8 = new JButton();
    buttond8.setText("d8");
    buttond8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});

    JButton buttond10 = new JButton();
    buttond10.setText("d10");
    buttond10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});


    JButton buttond12 = new JButton();
    buttond12.setText("d12");
    buttond12.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});

    JButton buttond20 = new JButton();
    buttond20.setText("d20");
    buttond20.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});

    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(buttond4);

    panel.add(buttond6);
    panel.add(buttond8);
    panel.add(buttond10);
    panel.add(buttond12);
    panel.add(buttond20);
    panel.add(label1);



    frame.add(output);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I have provided buttons d4  - extended code, the code for rest buttons is almost identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `System.out.println("You threw d4 and got " + n);` causes the print to the console.

You should use the [`JTextArea#append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append-java.lang.String-) method instead.
Your code would become:

```
final JTextArea output = new JTextArea(" a ");

JButton buttond4  = new JButton();
buttond4.setText("d4");
buttond4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        int n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        output.append("You threw d4 and got " + n + "\n");

    }
});
```

Edit:

You also need to add the `output` to the `JFrame`. You tried this by using

```
frame.add(output);
frame.add(panel);
```

but that won't work. The content pane of a `JFrame` by default has a `BorderLayout`, and calling `add` will add the component in the `BorderLayout#CENTER`. That area can only contain one component.

Now you have two options:

- Change the `LayoutManager`. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a good overview of the standard available `LayoutManager`s.
- Keep the current `LayoutManager`, and add the two components to different areas, e.g.

  ```
  frame.add(output, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  ```

Comment: but, i still dont get an output on the same frame as buttons. Code compiles, but does not give output...

Comment: @mr.robot You should have mentioned in your question that the `JTextArea` isn't even visible on the frame. I addressed this in the edit of my answer

Answer (score 0):

A little bit overkill, but I hope it can help - JAVA CODE:

```java
public class ConsolePanel {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    panel(
         21,
         2,
         3,
         3,
         Border.BOLD,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.THIN,
         true,
         true,
         "My Title", "My First Topic text", "My Second Topic text"
    );
  }

  public static void simplePanel(String... texts) {

    panel(
         21,
         5,
         1,
         1,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.THIN,
         Border.THIN,
         true,
         true,
         texts
    );
  }

  public static void simplePanelScalable(int scale, String... texts) {

    panel(
         scale,
         5,
         1,
         1,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.DOUBLE,
         Border.THIN,
         Border.THIN,
         true,
         true,
         texts
    );
  }

  public static void panel(
       int scale,
       int margin,
       int upSpace,
       int downSpace,
       Border cornersFormat,
       Border centerMarksFormat,
       Border horizontalLinesFormat,
       Border verticalLinesFormat,
       boolean uppercaseTitle,
       boolean centralizeTitle,
       String... titleAndOthers) {

    var estimatedAdjustmentFactor = 3;
    var title = titleAndOthers[0];
    var marginTitle = scale - (title.length() / 2) - estimatedAdjustmentFactor;
    var formattedTexts =
         Stream.of(titleAndOthers)
               .map(item -> item.equals(title) && centralizeTitle ? " ".repeat(
                    marginTitle) + title : item)
               .map(item -> item.equals(
                    title) && uppercaseTitle ? item.toUpperCase() : item)
               .toArray();

    var marginLimitedBySize = Math.min(margin, scale);

    // scale + margin discrepacies eliminated
    if (marginLimitedBySize % 2 != 0) -- marginLimitedBySize;
    if (scale % 2 != 0) ++ scale;

    int fullSize = (scale * 2) - marginLimitedBySize;
    if (fullSize % 2 == 0) ++ fullSize;
    else -- fullSize;

    var whitespaceMargin = " ".repeat(marginLimitedBySize);
    var externalUpSpaces = "\n".repeat(upSpace);
    var externalBottomSpaces = "\n".repeat(downSpace);

    var upperFace = upperLine(scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalLinesFormat);
    var divider = middleLine(scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalLinesFormat);
    var bottomFace = bottomLine(scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalLinesFormat);
    var faceLine = faceLine(verticalLinesFormat);

    var titleTextArea = String.valueOf(fullSize);
    var textPreparation = new StringBuilder();
    textPreparation.append(externalUpSpaces)
                   .append(upperFace)
                   .append(faceLine)
                   .append("%s%%-%ss".formatted(whitespaceMargin, titleTextArea))
                   .append(faceLine)
                   .append("\n")
                   .append(divider);

    // "-1" Because the first element in the Array was used as title
    // The discont-number in bodyTextArea/fullsize, subtract the size of "ordinal-ASC" and ") "
    var bodyTextArea = String.valueOf(fullSize - 4);
    var topicEnumeration = 0;
    var ordinalSymbolEnumerator = '\u2070';
    for (int i = formattedTexts.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      ++ topicEnumeration;
      textPreparation.append(faceLine)
                     .append("%s%s%s) %%-%ss".formatted(
                          whitespaceMargin,
                          topicEnumeration,
                          ordinalSymbolEnumerator,
                          bodyTextArea
                     ))
                     .append(faceLine)
                     .append("\n");
    }
    textPreparation.append(bottomFace)
                   .append(externalBottomSpaces);
    System.out.printf(textPreparation.toString(), formattedTexts);
  }

  private static String generateLine(char baseChar, int scale, char BASE_LINE) {

    return
         String
              .valueOf(baseChar)
              .repeat(scale)
              .replace(baseChar, BASE_LINE);
  }

  private static String upperLine(
       int scale,
       Border corner,
       Border centerMark,
       Border line) {

    ArrayList<Character> borderStylingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case THIN -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case DOUBLE -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    switch (line) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    var baseline = generateLine('_', scale, borderStylingItems.get(3));

    return borderStylingItems.get(0) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(2) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(1) + "\n";
  }

  private static String middleLine(
       int scale,
       Border corner,
       Border centerMark,
       Border baseLine
  ) {

    ArrayList<Character> borderStylingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code);
      }
      case THIN -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code);
      }
      case DOUBLE -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code);
      }
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    switch (baseLine) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    var divider = generateLine('_', scale, borderStylingItems.get(3));

    return borderStylingItems.get(0) + divider +
           borderStylingItems.get(2) + divider +
           borderStylingItems.get(1) + "\n";
  }

  private static String bottomLine(
       int scale,
       Border corner,
       Border centerMark,
       Border baseLine) {

    ArrayList<Character> borderStylingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case THIN -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
      case DOUBLE -> {
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code);
      }
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    switch (baseLine) {
      case BOLD -> borderStylingItems.add(BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case THIN -> borderStylingItems.add(ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code);
      case DOUBLE -> borderStylingItems.add(DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code);
    }

    var baseline = generateLine('_', scale, borderStylingItems.get(3));

    return borderStylingItems.get(0) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(2) + baseline +
           borderStylingItems.get(1) + "\n";
  }

  private static Character faceLine(Border corner) {

    return switch (corner) {
      case BOLD -> BoldFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      case THIN -> ThinFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      case DOUBLE -> DoubleFont.FACE_LINE.code;
    };
  }

  private enum BoldFont {

    FACE_LINE('\u2503'),
    BASE_LINE('\u2501'),
    UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250F'),
    UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2513'),
    MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2523'),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u252B'),
    LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2517'),
    LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u251B');

    private final char code;

    BoldFont(char code) {

      this.code = code;
    }
  }

  private enum ThinFont {

    FACE_LINE('\u2502'),
    BASE_LINE('\u2500'),
    UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250C'),
    UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2510'),
    MIDDLE_LEFT('\u252C'),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u2524'),
    LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2514'),
    LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2518');

    private final char code;

    ThinFont(char code) {

      this.code = code;
    }
  }

  private enum DoubleFont {

    FACE_LINE('\u2551'),
    BASE_LINE('\u2550'),
    UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2554'),
    UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2557'),
    MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2560'),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u2563'),
    LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u255A'),
    LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u255D');

    private final char code;

    DoubleFont(char code) {

      this.code = code;
    }
  }

  private enum Border {
    BOLD, THIN, DOUBLE
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Check It in: https://github.com/codegtd/tdd-log-panel

Answer (score 0):

Thats a code version in Dart/Flutter

Check It in: https://github.com/codegtd/tdd-log-panel-flutter-dart

```
// @formatter:off
void main() {

  DartPanel().scalablePanel(
      scale: 21,
      texts: ["Simple Panel Scalable", "My First Topic"]);

  DartPanel().simplePanel(
      texts: ["Simple Panel", "My First Topic"]);

  DartPanel().panel(
        scale: 21,
        margin: 2,
        upSpace: 3,
        downSpace: 3,
        cornersFormat: _Border.BOLD,
        centerMarksFormat: _Border.DOUBLE,
        horizontalFacesFormat: _Border.DOUBLE,
        lateralFacesFormat: _Border.THIN,
        isUppercaseTitle: true,
        isCentralizedTitle: true,
        titleAndOthers: ["My Panel","First Topic","Second Topic"]);
  }

class DartPanel {

  void simplePanel({
    required List<String> texts}) {
    panel(
        scale: 21,
        margin: 5,
        upSpace: 1,
        downSpace: 1,
        cornersFormat: _Border.DOUBLE,
        centerMarksFormat: _Border.DOUBLE,
        horizontalFacesFormat: _Border.THIN,
        lateralFacesFormat: _Border.THIN,
        isUppercaseTitle: true,
        isCentralizedTitle: true,
        titleAndOthers:texts);
  }

  void scalablePanel({
    required int scale,
    required List<String> texts}) {
    panel(
        scale: scale,
        margin:5,
        upSpace: 1,
        downSpace: 1,
        cornersFormat: _Border.DOUBLE,
        centerMarksFormat: _Border.DOUBLE,
        horizontalFacesFormat: _Border.THIN,
        lateralFacesFormat: _Border.THIN,
        isUppercaseTitle: true,
        isCentralizedTitle: true,
        titleAndOthers: texts);
  }

  void panel({
    required int scale,
    required int margin,
    required int upSpace,
    required int downSpace,
    required _Border cornersFormat,
    required _Border centerMarksFormat,
    required _Border horizontalFacesFormat,
    required _Border lateralFacesFormat,
    required bool isUppercaseTitle,
    required bool isCentralizedTitle,
    required List<String> titleAndOthers,}
  ) {
    var estimatedAdjustmentFactor = 3;
    var title = titleAndOthers[0];
    var marginTitle = scale - (title.length / 2).round() - estimatedAdjustmentFactor;
    var titleAndTopics =
    titleAndOthers
     .map((item) => item == title && isCentralizedTitle ? (' ' * marginTitle) + title : item)
     .map((item) => item == title && isUppercaseTitle ? item.toUpperCase() : item)
     .toList();

    var marginLimitedBySize = margin < scale ? margin : scale;

    /*╔════════════════════════════════════════╗
      ║ scale + margin discrepacies eliminated ║
      ╚════════════════════════════════════════╝*/
    if (marginLimitedBySize.isOdd) --marginLimitedBySize;
    if (scale.isOdd) ++scale;

    int fullSize = (scale * 2) - marginLimitedBySize;
    if (fullSize.isEven) ++fullSize; else --fullSize;

    var topicMargin = (' ' * marginLimitedBySize);
    var externalUpSpaces = '\n' * upSpace;
    var externalBottomSpaces = '\n' * downSpace;

    var upperFace = _createUpperFace(
      scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalFacesFormat);

    var dividerFace = _createDividerFace(
      scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalFacesFormat);

    var bottomFace = _createBottomFace(
      scale, cornersFormat, centerMarksFormat, horizontalFacesFormat);

    var leftLateralFace = _createLateralFace(lateralFacesFormat);
    var rightLateralFace = _createLateralFace(lateralFacesFormat);

    var titleTextArea = ' ' * (fullSize - titleAndTopics[0].length - 2);
    var textPreparation = StringBuffer()
      ..write(externalUpSpaces)
      ..write(upperFace)
      ..write(rightLateralFace)
      ..write('$topicMargin ${titleAndTopics[0]} $titleTextArea')
      ..write(leftLateralFace)
      ..write('\n')
      ..write(dividerFace);

    /*╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
      ║ "-1" Because the first element in the Array was used as title ║
      ║ The discont-number in fillUpSpaces/fullsize, subtract the size║
      ║ of "ordinal-ASC" and ") "                                     ║
      ╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝*/
    var topicEnumerator = 0;
    var symbolEnumerator = '\u2070';
    for (int i = titleAndTopics.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      ++topicEnumerator;
      var fillUpSpaces = ' ' * (fullSize - titleAndTopics[topicEnumerator].length - 4);
      textPreparation
        ..write(leftLateralFace)
        ..write(
            '$topicMargin'
            '$topicEnumerator'
            '$symbolEnumerator) '
            '${titleAndTopics[topicEnumerator]}'
            '$fillUpSpaces')
        ..write(leftLateralFace)
        ..write('\n');
    }

    textPreparation
      ..write(bottomFace)
      ..write(externalBottomSpaces);

    print('$textPreparation');
  }

  String _createLateralFace(_Border corner) {
    switch (corner) {
      case _Border.BOLD:   return _BoldFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      case _Border.THIN:   return _ThinFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      case _Border.DOUBLE: return _DoubleFont.FACE_LINE.code;
      default:             return '';
    }
  }



  String _createUpperFace(
      int scale,
      _Border corner,
      _Border centerMark,
      _Border line) {
    List<String> borderStylingItems = [];

    switch (corner) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code); break;
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
    }

    switch (line) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
    }

    String upperFace = _faceGenerator('_', ((scale * 2)+1), borderStylingItems[2]);

    return borderStylingItems[0] + upperFace + borderStylingItems[1] + "\n";
  }

  String _createDividerFace(
      int scale,
      _Border corner,
      _Border centerMark,
      _Border baseLine) {
    List<String> borderStylingItems = [];
    switch (corner) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code); break;
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
    }

    switch (baseLine) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
    }

    var panelDivider = _faceGenerator('_', scale, borderStylingItems[3]);

    return
        borderStylingItems[0] +
        panelDivider +
        borderStylingItems[2] +
        panelDivider +
        borderStylingItems[1] +
        "\n";
  }

  String _createBottomFace(
      int scale,
      _Border corner,
      _Border centerMark,
      _Border baseLine,
      ) {
    List<String> borderStylingItems = [];

    switch (corner) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code);
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code); break;
    }

    switch (centerMark) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
    }

    switch (baseLine) {
      case _Border.BOLD:
        borderStylingItems.add(_BoldFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.THIN:
        borderStylingItems.add(_ThinFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
      case _Border.DOUBLE:
        borderStylingItems.add(_DoubleFont.BASE_LINE.code); break;
    }

    var bottonFace = _faceGenerator('_', scale, borderStylingItems[3]);

    return
        borderStylingItems[0] +
        bottonFace +
        borderStylingItems[2] +
        bottonFace +
        borderStylingItems[1] +
        "\n";
  }

  String _faceGenerator(
      String baseChar,
      int scale,
      String BASE_LINE) {
    return (baseChar * scale).replaceAll(baseChar, BASE_LINE);
  }
}

enum _BoldFont {
  FACE_LINE('\u2503'),
  BASE_LINE('\u2501'),
  UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250F'),
  UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2513'),
  MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2523'),
  MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u252B'),
  LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2517'),
  LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u251B');

  final String code;

  const _BoldFont(this.code);
}

enum _ThinFont {
  FACE_LINE('\u2502'),
  BASE_LINE('\u2500'),
  UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250C'),
  UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2510'),
  MIDDLE_LEFT('\u252C'),
  MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u2524'),
  LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2514'),
  LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2518');

  final String code;

  const _ThinFont(this.code);
}

enum _DoubleFont {
  FACE_LINE('\u2551'),
  BASE_LINE('\u2550'),
  UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2554'),
  UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2557'),
  MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2560'),
  MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u2563'),
  LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u255A'),
  LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u255D');

  final String code;

  const _DoubleFont(this.code);
}

enum _Border { BOLD, THIN, DOUBLE }
// @formatter:on
```